# Is it possible to import global types in libraries (like "dom") explicitly?

Tags: typescript

When consuming builtins like libdom, the entirety of the dom types are included into the global scope (exactly as they are when running JS in the browser).

My issue is, in larger applications or mono repos, having ambient types can cause naming collisions and ambiguous functionality.

**Shadowed global variable names**

The removal of shadowed global variables will not cause a type error as expected. As an example, if you name a variable `name`

```js
const name = 'foo'
console.log(name)
```

Then you later delete `name`

```js
console.log(name)
```

Any logic further down that depends on it will still work because it assumes you're referring to `window.name`.

**Unexpected global overwrites**

This can also cause issues where certain libraries will override the globals.

For instance if you have a mono repo with a backend and frontend together, the definition for `setTimeout` is different in `@types/node` than it is in `dom` and there is a collision.

If you install `styled-components` (or have another package using React Native) then they will use the globals for React Native which override `fetch` and `Headers`.

**Incorrect context specific globals**

What if the file I am working in is a Web Worker or Service Worker? These contexts don't have all the functionality of libdom but are offered global types that indicate that they do.

**Dependency injection**

Lastly, explicit imports are better when it comes to reasoning about dependency injection.

**Question**

I would love to be able to import global dependencies directly, is such a thing possible?

example:

```js
import { window, console, Window } from 'libdom'

function foo(windowRef: Window) {
  console.log(windowRef.location.href)
}

foo(window)
```

EDIT: Also I am not talking about built-in language features like `Array.filter`, `Proxy`, or similar. I'm specifically referring to environment specific functionality like `MessageChannel`, `Fetch`, `Location`, etc

Comment: I have raised the issue in the Typescript repo: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46754